# Why redux onclick action in reactjs app isnt working?

Tags: reactjs, redux, action

Here is simplified code:

-action.js

```
export const removeVisitedUser = id => async dispatch => {
        try  {
        const visited = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`visited_`)) || [];
        const filtered = visited.filter(i => i !== id);
        debugger
        dispatch({type: REMOVE_VISITED_USER, payload: {filtered}})
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({ type: ERROR_REMOVE_VISITED_USER }, err)
    }

}

export const errorRemoveVisitedUser = () => ({
    type: ERROR_REMOVE_VISITED_USER
});
```

-reducer.js

```
import { REMOVE_VISITED_USER } from "./action";


const initialState = {
    visited: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`visited_`)) || [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    const { visited } = state;
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case REMOVE_VISITED_USER: {
            return { ...state, visited: payload.filtered};

};
```

-reactComponent.js

```
const reactComponent= ({
    visited: { visited},
    removeVisitedUser,
}) => {
return (
        <div className="visited-list">
            <div className="visited-list__items">
                <MyLogo />
                {visited.map((i, ind) => (
                    <div
                        key={ind}
                        onClick={() => removeVisitedUser(i._id)}
                        className={`visited-list__item ${active(ind)}`}
                    >

                        {!i.img
                            ? <i className="fa fa-user-circle" />
                            : <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${avatarGetter(i.img)})` }} />}
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

You can see debugger in removing action, as i know it should run when I click on any visited user div, but it didnt, so action didnt work too.

I spend a lot of time to understand how it should work properly, but still didnt figure out.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you connected your `reactComponent` to Redux? Also keep in mind to name components pascal-case. e.g. `VisitedList` or `ReactComponent`. If you like I can create a small Redux demo to show how to connect a component.

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-cohen-yd8rm?file=/src/App.js) you can find a small example of how to connect your component to Redux. If you like I can add an answer with some explanation. You won't need the `async` in your action as getting/setting data in localStorage is running synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I cant see you using `mapDispatchToProps` anywhere. can you provide this code? or if you don't have it you'll need to add it so that react knows to use it as a prop

Comment: I`m using mapDispatchToProps like this:

export default withRouter(connect(state => ({ visited: state.visited}), {
    removeVisitedUser
})(reactComponent));